# Android java.security.cert.CertificateException in Lower Version

Tags: java, android, ssl

I keep getting this error on Android Version lower than 4.0 while using SSL certificates. Kindly assist.

```
05-26 18:13:21.230: W/System.err(452): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
05-26 18:13:21.230: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:477)
05-26 18:13:21.230: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:750)
05-26 18:13:21.230: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:692)
05-26 18:13:21.240: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.<init>(SocketInputBuffer.java:93)
05-26 18:13:21.240: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:83)
05-26 18:13:21.240: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:170)
05-26 18:13:21.240: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:106)
05-26 18:13:21.240: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:129)
05-26 18:13:21.240: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:171)
05-26 18:13:21.240: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-26 18:13:21.240: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-26 18:13:21.250: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
05-26 18:13:21.250: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-26 18:13:21.250: W/System.err(452):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-26 18:13:21.250: W/System.err(452):  at HttpsConnection.getResponseFromHttpPostRequest(HttpsConnection.java:186)
05-26 18:13:21.260: W/System.err(452):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
05-26 18:13:21.260: W/System.err(452):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
05-26 18:13:21.260: W/System.err(452):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
05-26 18:13:21.260: W/System.err(452):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
05-26 18:13:21.260: W/System.err(452):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
05-26 18:13:21.260: W/System.err(452):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
05-26 18:13:21.270: W/System.err(452): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException
```

This code is throwing the exception:

```
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException { 
    for (X509TrustManager tm : x509TrustManagers) { 
        try { 
            tm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType); 
            return; 
        } catch (CertificateException e) { /* ignore */ } 
    } 
    throw new CertificateException(); 
}
```

Comment: Please provide the URL you are trying to access - or is this behavior independent of the target host?

Comment: Its independent. I invoked another https: url  Same issse for Android version lower than 4.2

Comment: If this is really independent of the URL then it must be a problem with your code (which you did not show), since there is working TLS support for Android < 4.2. Maybe check some more URL? And try some target hosts which definitely don't need SNI, like google.com.

Comment: This is function throwing the exception     public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
    throws CertificateException {
   for (X509TrustManager tm : x509TrustManagers) {
    try {
     tm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
     return;
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
     // ignore
    }
   }
   throw new CertificateException();
  }

Comment: I don't think we are getting near the root of the problem with only this few information and badly formatted fragments of the code which probably are no use without more context anyway.

Comment: I created a keystore with the server ssl certificate using Bouncing Castle. The above exception if for Android <4.2 when invoking the url